# Basic MVC design: views

Tags: java, model-view-controller

So there are two different views(controllers are merged into views):

**View 1**: Tabular view. There is a table and a number of buttons on top of the table.

**View 2**: Text view. There is a text area and a number of buttons which are distinct from the buttons in Tabular view.

There is one model file for two views files to link.

I also create a main.java file to declare the main window,a tabbed pane(to switch views) and bind views to it.

As a noob java developer and MVC design pattern learner, I was wondering:

**1. What is the correct way to declare buttons, the table and text area?**

For example, for View 1(Tabular), are its buttons and table declared in the view or in the main.java?

**2. If declared in views, how are they added in the main window?** Default UpdateAllViews() doesn't seem to go through the main window in main.java.

At this point, I am only aware that model should never ever have anything like JButton declared in it as model itself should not be aware about what the window and stuff looks and feels. I can see that controllers are sort of binded to a certain view componenet, but the view itself gets me very confused.

If anyone can provide a shortcut to get deeper understanding of MVC pattern, I'd be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Please keep in your mind that you are dealing with objects. And the Model, View and Controller are categories/collections of objects.

Your model objects are instances of classes relating to your business domain. e.g. if you are making an address book, you would have an ADDRESS class.

Your View objects provide a connection to your users. e.g. SEARCHDIALOG class and ADDRESSDIALOG class.

Your Controller provides the bindings/interface into your system (the systems API). you will have one controller that represents the system, e.g. ADDRESSBOOKAPP class.

Enjoy.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't address the actual question of y26jin which was how GUI elements fit into the MVC pattern.

Comment: Ah good point: The View objects will typically form a hierarchy, which can contain (composition) instances of JBUTTONs etc.